# PHP compare dates

Tags: php, date, compare

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php date compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143741/php-date-compare)

I have a date that I take from the mySQL database that looks like this:

```
2011-06-20
```

And I get the date of the current day in this way:

```
$todaydate = date('Y-m-d');
```

What I need to know is how do I compare the two results?

How can I compare the dates and understand for example if a week is passed from the database date or a month or a year..etc..?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to put that burden on PHP when MySQL has built-in functionality for that already. You should take a look at MySQL's [`DATEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function:

> `DATEDIFF()` returns `expr1` – `expr2` expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. `expr1` and `expr2` are date or date-and-time expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation.

An example of two dates that'd give a 7-day difference could be:

```
mysql> select datediff('2011-06-18','2011-06-25');
+-------------------------------------+
| datediff('2011-06-18','2011-06-25') |
+-------------------------------------+
|                                  -7 | 
+-------------------------------------+
```

This means that the first date occured -7 days after the first date; that's 7 days *before*. If you let the two arguments switch place, the result would be a positive 7.

Comment: Could you provide an example? For example for 7 days difference? I do not really know where to start! Thank you!

Comment: I've added an example. More examples are available at the documentation linked in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about considering using UNIX_TIMESTAMP? It uses the concept of elapsed time.

Comment: it's prone to the 2038 date limit... ;)

Comment: @Frankie 2038 is in the ... *future*~

Comment: @thephpdeveloper have you seen any of those blockbuster's movies that destroy the world as we know it but keep your web-server running? There. I guess you can add a cron to 2037 to reset your date back to 1970...

Comment: if programmers behave and use time_t type, instead of the uint32 type, we are safe! time_t is bound to get changed to a uint64 before the uint32 overflow... or so i hope

Comment: @Frankie I know all the over flow stuff. just sayin'

Answer (score 1):

The "old" way to compare two or more dates is to convert then to an unix timestamp (seconds in float) using strtotime() function. For example:

```
if((strtotime('2011-05-10') - strtotime('2011-05-01')) > 604800)
{
    echo('A week has passed');
}

if((strtotime('2011-06-10') - strtotime('2011-05-01')) > 2629743)
{
    echo('A month has passed');
}
```

Or the "new" way is to use the DateTime class bundled with PHP 5.2 or newer. Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php.

Answer (score 0):

And of course [date_diff](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) has plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider what you are exactly looking for.

- Are you looking to filter dates older than a week? You can do that comparison on the SQL and you don't burden PHP with date comparisons.
- Are you wanting a date difference? Again, I suggest putting it in SQL and just display the result.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the number of seconds between the two dates:

```
<?php
$time = '2011-06-20';
$timeDiff = time() - strtotime($time);
echo $timeDiff;
?>
```

You could divide this value by 86,400 to get the number of days, and so on.

Comment: That can get tripped up by daylight saving changes, especially if you need more precision than "1 day". It is not recommended.