# Compare two dates in in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php date compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143741/php-date-compare)
>   [PHP compare dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405910/php-compare-dates)

I have this code which permits me to grab today's date in this format:

```
 $today = date("d-m-Y");
```

Then this query:

```
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($queryenddate)) { 
$end_date=$row1['end_date'];
}
```

The end date prints something like : 12-02-2012

How can i compare this two dates?
What do i need to do?
Thanks

Comment: please show the value of $queryenddate

Comment: What do you need to compare about them ??

Comment: I need to compare the whole date, i mean which is bigger than the other, if today's date is bigger or not

Comment: i mean if 12-02-2012 is bigger or not than 12-09-2012 i.e

Comment: what shows var_dump($row1['end_date']); ?

Comment: There are millions of duplicates in the Related Questions. Please search before you ask a question.

Comment: Convert the date to timestamp, then you can compare the dates easily

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `DateTime`

```
$today = new DateTime();
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", $end_date);

if ($today > $date) {
    // Totaay is more current
}

if ($today->format("m") == $date->format("m")) {
    // they have same month
}
```

You can also do something like this

```
$diffrence = $today->diff($date); //enddate is "01-01-2010"
var_dump($diffrence);
```

Output

```
object(DateInterval)[3]
  public 'y' => int 2
  public 'm' => int 8
  public 'd' => int 24
  public 'h' => int 0
  public 'i' => int 0
  public 's' => int 0
  public 'invert' => int 1
  public 'days' => int 998
```

Comment: hey thanks. if i use it like you said, it says:  Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Comment: @Tao see demo : http://codepad.viper-7.com/EnIq8B  what is your version of PHP ???

Comment: Hey thanks :)
i'll take a look at it, i'm on localhost, have no idea... but thanks!

Answer (score 6):

you can compare this by

```
if(strtotime($date1)>strtotime($date2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the strtotime () function to convert a date into a number, then you can use for comparisons or opereaciones.

```
 $today = date("d-m-Y"); 

 $end_date='02-09-2012';

 echo $today;
 echo "<br>".$end_date;

 $diference= (strtotime($end_date)-strtotime($today))/86400;
 $diference= abs($diference); 
 $diference= floor($diference);

  echo "<br>".$diference;
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is that this one calculates the day..
i need a whole calculation, month year included